# internet explorer 8 css compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

made a navigiation bar that changes photo on hover. It works well on my firefox but at my work all the computers still uses IE 8 and the bar wont show at all.

will making it with js will make it better ?
i know how to code using only css and js

```css
nav{
    background-color: #fff;
    width:150px;
    height: 667px;
    float:right;
}

nav h1{
    padding: 20px;
    color: #777;
    font: 20px tahoma,times,serif;

}
ul {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: right;
 }
ul li {
 position: relative;
 }
li ul {
 position: absolute;
 right: 149px;
 top: 0;
 display: none;
 }
ul li a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #777;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 5px;

 border-bottom: 0;
 }
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 150px;

 }
li:hover ul {
     display: block;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #333;
    background: url("http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/6/69/FC-Barcelona-old-logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20120211172615");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 500px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 800px;
}
.container img{
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -60;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
}
.container li img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -50;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;   
}

li:nth-child(1){
    padding-top: 0px;
}

li a:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

li:hover a +img {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0px auto;
  left: 0px auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <LINK rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <nav><h1><b>ברצלונה</b></h1>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">ברצלונה</a><img src="http://media3.fcbarcelona.com/media/asset_publics/resources/000/160/456/size_640x360/pic_2015-01-11_BARCELONA-ATLETICO_45.v1431011244.JPG" alt="1"></li> 
  <li><a href="#">לה ליגה</a><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTd6ngNNGapdLhqdS4KbuoNNCaaUMP4Svu-e_9rXMh_wLDtPpSE" alt="1">
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">ברצלונה</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">ריאל</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">אתלטיקו</a></li> 
      </ul>
      
    </li> 
  <li><a href="#">בונדסליגה</a><img src="http://static3.demotix.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/a_scale_large/2000-5/photos/1368393557-club-atletico-de-madrid-v-fc-barcelona--la-liga_2046465.jpg" alt="1"> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">באיירן</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">וולפסבורג</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">הנדובר</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">דורטמונד</a></li>  
      </ul> 
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">סיירה א</a><img src="http://barcelonacamps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/barca-new-team.jpg" alt="1"> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">אינטר</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">מילאן</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">יובה</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">רומא</a></li> 
      </ul> 
      </ul>
    </li> 
            </nav>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In some cases I've came across it didn't work in some browsers when specifiying same thing twice in the css (I can't recall which browser though). I see that you're defining ul twice for example. Try to define ul only once and put all rules in there. Even if this doesn't fix the problem it's easier to read and maintain :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the css or js but the html, you're using html 5 elements on html4 browser.
Consider using a polyfill js: https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv
Or using html4 elements only.